# Integrate a function of an interpolating function

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to plot the integral of an interpolating function multiplied by another (analytic) function, eg:

```
    sol = NDSolve[{ x''[t] == 1.0, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}, {x'[t], 
   x[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}]
```

then form some integral

```
f[t_] = Integrate[ t x'[t] /. sol, t]
```

and try to plot it

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

This works fine if the integrand doesn't contain an analytic function (t, in the example above), but not if it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is use `NIntegrate`

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] == 1.0, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}, {x'[t], 
   x[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}]
f[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[t*x'[t] /. sol, {t, 0, s}];
 Plot[f[s], {s, 0, 1}]
```

Another way is add `y'[t]=t*x'[t]`.

```
sol2= NDSolve[{x''[t] == 1.0, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0, y'[t] == t*x'[t],
     y[0] == 0}, {y[t], x'[t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}];
Plot[y[t] /. sol2, {t, 0, 1}]
```